# Newline, EOF and feof() aren't acknowledged

Tags: c, newline, eof, fgetc

I have a function that does the following:

```
ssize_t headache(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE * stream)
{
    if(lineptr != NULL)
    {
            free(*lineptr);
    }
    size_t  len     = 0,
            last    = 0;
    char *  buf     = NULL;
    int c;

    do
    { 
            last = len;
            ++len;
            buf = realloc(buf,len);
            c = fgetc(stream);
            buf[last] = (char)c;
            printf("%i\t%x\t%c\n", last, buf[last], buf[last]);
    }
    while(!feof(stream) || c != '\n');
    *n = strlen(buf);
    *lineptr = buf;
    return len;
}
```

headache is always called headache(&lineptr,&n,stream) where

```
char * lineptr = NULL;
size_t n = 0;
FILE * stream;
```

The do{}while(); loop will never acknowledge a newline or EOF, meaning that it will continue in infinity. I don't understand why is it ignoring EOF and '\n'. Can someone please tell me what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(!feof(stream) || c != '\n');
```

will loop again unless both conditions evaluate to false.  You want to exit the loop when you either receive `EOF` or `\n` so should use `&&` instead

```
while(!feof(stream) && c != '\n');
```

Comment: I thought || would mean that if either one condition is met, the loop will exit.

Comment: That actually kinda worked. But now it keeps reading the first line from stream over and over again.

Comment: A quick revision of the main() this function is called from made me realize that it was wrongly implemented. A little change done and it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.  Regarding your first comment, `||` is the logical OR operator and evaluates to true unless both its operands are 0 (false)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with

`while(!feof(stream) || c != '\n')`

this is because using || (or) you have to make both conditions false for it to stop execution. There are inputs that would make your while loop never end. `this is a test input` vs. `this is a test input\n`.

If you are running this as stdin as your `file*` compare what happens when you run it with you typing a message and pressing enter and you typing a message and pressing control-d (which is EOF in a terminal)

As stated by simonc you need the && operator which only requires one of the conditions to be false for it to stop.

Comment: This is not a standard input. It's usually has stream = fopen(argv[1],"r");

Comment: you can try to open the file in an editor of your choice (VIM for me) and see if it can list the hidden chars (in vim its :list) this atleast will show you if there is a \n at the end of the file.